# Change in another Workbook impacts UDF in main Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have developed a User Defined Funtion (UDF) in a VBA module and it works for its purpose.
However, when I change anything in another open workbook which is not related to the main workbook at all, all those cell values in my mai workbook, which uses this UDF will be erased. I then have to let Excel calculate those cells again.

Why does this happen? Can I prevent that? I need this kind of "live" calculation inside that workbook. Any hints appreciated.

If it helps, see code below:

```
Private Function CalculateAcrossAmounts(iHeaderRow As Integer, rngRow As Range, Optional VolatileParameter As Variant) As Double
    Call declareVariables
    Application.Volatile
    CalculateAcrossAmounts = 0
    For i = iColStart To lngLastCol
            If wsScopingMatrix.Cells(rngRow.Row, i) <> "" And wsScopingMatrix.Cells(rngRow.Row, i) <> 0 Then
                CalculateAcrossAmounts = CalculateAcrossAmounts + 1
            End If
    Next i
End Function
```

EDIT: Code for Sub DeclareVariables

```
Sub declareVariables()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsScopingMatrix = wb.Sheets("GA_Scoping_Matrix")
    Set wsMasterData = wb.Sheets("MasterData")
    
    iColLabel = 1            'Spalte, wo TA/TR eingetragen wird
    iRowCategory = 12        'Reihe, wo die Kategorien ausgewählt werden
    iRowHeader = 13          'Reihe wo die Header (Entities) sind
    iColStart = 11 '9
    iColxGroupMateriality = 6
    
    dblGroupMateriality = wsScopingMatrix.Range("rngGroupMateriality")
    
    lngLastRow = getLastRow(wsScopingMatrix, 2)
    lngLastCol = getLastCol(wsScopingMatrix, iRowHeader)
    
    For i = 1 To lngLastRow
        If wsScopingMatrix.Cells(i, iColLabel) = "TA" Then iRowTA = i
        If wsScopingMatrix.Cells(i, iColLabel) = "TR" Then iRowTR = i
        If wsScopingMatrix.Cells(i, iColLabel) = "OB" Then iRowOB = i
    Next i

     clrZentralGepruefterAccount = wsMasterData.Range("A3").Interior.Color
     clrFullScopeAudit = wsMasterData.Range("A4").Interior.Color
     clrAuditOfAccountBalance = wsMasterData.Range("A5").Interior.Color
     clrSpecifiedAuditProcedures = wsMasterData.Range("A6").Interior.Color
     clrHighlightBenchmarkAccount = wsMasterData.Range("A11").Font.Color
End Sub
```

before change in another workbook:

[image]

after change in another workbook:

[image]

Comment: What is the code for `declareVariables`?

Comment: @Rory See the edit in my post.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems with the code there. Have you debugged to check what the *source* cell values are when the function is recalculating?

Comment: I thought about your question, there is another UDF which impacts that one, and there I did not explicitly specify the worksheet of a cell. I found the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The UDF function is calculated each time Excel Calculate.

If there are other function(s) in that `the other workbook` having the line `Application.Volatile`, this will be the result when something is changed.

According to your needs, you can make `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` followed by `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` when you need to avoid such a behavior...

Comment: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic followed by the same again?

Comment: @smartini: No! Only after you need to get out of the 'break' in calculations... :) But if a cell targeted by your UDF function has been changed, when the Calculation will be again Automatic, the result will be the same. This suggestion works only if for a temporary period some changes must be done and finally the initial value is kept... But my answer is not so appropriate. I did not pay attention to the fact that your function return is modified. I only tried giving an explanation about the reason of recalculation.